# sudo with WS2812 and Raspberry Pi

Tags: pwm, sudo, root, ws2812

I'm trying to use the Neopixel Adafruit library with the WS2812 strip. Everything works great however there is something that I have not been able to do.

I'm working on a project that requires several libraries to be implemented on one script, and to run the Neopixel library I have to use the sudo command in the terminal. I'm trying to avoid this because of streamlining but mainly because if I do use sudo, then my python versions won't be compatible with other libraries. At the end of the day, my goal is to be able to run a python script in Thonny by NOT having to type sudo in to the terminal every time. I'd like to be able to give Thonny root access, give a user complete root access, or something along those lines.

Thanks in advance.

*Note*
I've tried to gksudo Thonny but it gives me a weird message and doesn't seem to give Thonny the root access I need it to have.

Comment: This question is too vague, but fundamentally insoluble. Python is an interpreted language, and Linux prohibits scripts from inheriting sudo permissions. It can be done in c or similar.

Comment: So these LEDs require PWM which is apparently only accessible using root access. However, from what you tell me, i cannot give this script root access. Is there anyway to run a script that requires root access without manually typing the "sudo python xxx.py" terminal command?

Comment: Incidentally WS2812 **DO NOT** use PWM, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26040/8697

Comment: Interesting. So i've tried giving GPIO access using the chown root.gpio /dev/mem method and i'm still getting nothing.

Comment: Although the signals are not PWM the Pi PWM hardware is used to generate them.  The Pi PWM hardware can be programmed to provide a variety of different signals.  You need sudo permissions to access the PWM registers.

Comment: "it gives me a weird message" - either that message is not relevant to the question (so don't mention it) or it is (and then it should be included).

Answer (score 0):

> give a user complete root access

Either login as root, or assign your user UID and GID of 0 in `/etc/passwd`.

> give Thonny root access

Either Thonny is a binary (or has a binary wrapper) on which you can set the `setuid` bit with `chmod u+s binary`, or you can build such a wrapper yourself ([example](https://github.com/jfredrickson/setuid-wrapper)). The reasons why `setuid` won't work on scripts in most cases are described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts). Note that there are programs which will refuse to run as root (`tor` and `google-chrome` to name a few), depending on the "weird message" you've seen that may be the case with Thonny as well.

In both cases, you create security holes, which is probably not relevant for a standalone LED strip controller, but it may become a problem if your RPi doubles as an HTTP/SSH server or is accessible to untrusted parties in other ways.